# Java - Define intervals of time with Joda

Tags: java, date, time, jodatime, intervals

I have to model intervals of time that a commerce is open, for example: monday to friday 10hs-18hs, and with a function check if the commerce is open or not. I think the most rational is using the class "Interval" that Joda provides, but I can't instantiate an Interval only with days or hours. I must use Joda.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting javadoc of [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html):

> A time interval represents a period of time between two **instants**.

Since "Monday at 10:00" is not an instant, you cannot use `Interval`.

The Joda-Time library doesn't have a class for what you want, so you'll have to write it yourself.

The requirement of "must use JODA" simple means that your class should take a `LocalDateTime` as input and use Joda-Time for querying the weekday and time-of-day.

---

A good reusable class (e.g. called `OpenCalendar`) might be used like this:

```
OpenCalendar openCal = new OpenCalendar();
openCal.add(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY   , new LocalTime(10, 0), new LocalTime(18, 0));
openCal.add(DateTimeConstants.TUESDAY  , new LocalTime(10, 0), new LocalTime(18, 0));
openCal.add(DateTimeConstants.WEDNESDAY, new LocalTime(10, 0), new LocalTime(18, 0));
openCal.add(DateTimeConstants.THURSDAY , new LocalTime(10, 0), new LocalTime(18, 0));
openCal.add(DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY   , new LocalTime(10, 0), new LocalTime(18, 0));

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
if (openCal.isOpen(now)) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: The original poster may also find the Joda-Time [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) and [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html) classes of use, both capturing a span of time not tied to the timeline.